# Differing values of liquidity tokens in Uniswap, when using the same formula

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider

I implemented the logic of the uniswap protocol on my blockchain using uniswap v2 whitepaper. To check if its working, I am comparing it with real examples of creating liquidity. I come across examples of calculating the creation of a liquidity pool with different results, which are described by the `sminted = √(xdeposited · ydeposited)` formula. Here are some of them:

Correct calculation for example [Uniswap V2: COIN 11](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf9fef7255ba27c4a245f692c94e3b350895a51e141c04b10ecc3d10410cc4eef) :

```
10000000e18 * 1900e18 = 19000000000e36
sqrt(19000000000e36) - 1000 = 137840487520902217678559
```

Incorrect calculation for the [Uniswap V2: USDT 2](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe64069acd123ec94b8a3316378183ba8bf42b40979df3b0bb57b0e7b9e47ef38) example:

```
sqrt(1.103511e18 * 0.005e18) - 1000 = 74280245364 // but in the transaction itself, the number of pool shares is 74280245364
```

Also, here are some more correct and incorrect calculations: [USDT-HUB](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6fd6a497c56c8e5e3709f47aff19ae9bfa0377b37e9baa7d50b75564e92bafc3) incorrect, [correct](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x691a026bd9a84bcf4e66e5ab8f060dc12d5ec86fb6757bc3fa0af0b4eafb0596), [incorrect](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x840abb27b060d1a9f16f0c5969b2fef0468799950d23c93b52e491666f454459), [incorrect](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x8adb1626a26e181a49f655dd917c36d75b7092d5581ecc48441999cf149bb075), [correct](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x630a62284659519a9eff849da2fca728632af7745185bbf17d5a295adf3cd7aa), [incorrect](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe7918f400ddbf4722f82b2c215e0e9ecb1cb3f1fc37e95cb56e4065db0203fda).

Could I have missed something in the calculations?

Comment: There is no question here!

Comment: could I have missed something in the calculations?